# Representing complex numbers as matrices, show that $A(z)+A(z')=A(z+z')$

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I am doing a task where in which I am representing complex numbers as matrices, so $z=x+iy \in \Bbb C$ is represented by:

$A(z)=\begin{bmatrix} 
x & -y \\
y & x 
\end{bmatrix}$

Now I have to show for all $z, z' \in\Bbb C$ that $A(z)+A(z')=A(z+z')$

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Let $z=x+iy, z'=a+ib$, compute $z+z'$ and then according to the definition of $A$, find $A(z), A(z')$ and $A(z+z')$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $z=x+iy,$ then $x=\frac12(z+\overline z)$ and $y=\frac1{2i}(z-\overline z)$. This shows you that $$A(z)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12(z+\overline z) & -\frac1{2i}(z-\overline z)\\\frac1{2i}(z-\overline z) & \frac12(z+\overline z)\end{bmatrix}$$ for any $z\in\Bbb C.$ Recalling the fact that $\overline{z+w}=\overline z+\overline w$ for any $z,w\in\Bbb C,$ can you take it from there?

Alternately, you can simply put $z=x+iy$ and $z'=x'+iy'$ where $x,y,x',y'\in\Bbb R,$ and proceed with the calculation directly, once you've put $z+z'$ into the form $a+ib,$ where $a,b\in\Bbb R.$

Comment: Thanks for that. I used the second part to prove it.

Comment: Quick side note question, how could I compute the inverse matrix of $A(z)$?

Comment: @Harry See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices).

Comment: @Harry: Note that if $x,y$ not both zero, then the inverse of $x+iy$ is $\frac1{x^2+y^2}(x-iy)=\frac1{|z|^2}\overline{z}.$ This suggests that $$A^{-1}(z)=\frac1{|z|^2}A(\overline z),$$ which does turn out to be the case, when we calculate the inverse of the matrix by the usual methods.